# Vaadin 14: cannot set HTML value by attribute to vaadin rich text editor

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I want to set the html value of a rich text editor component by attribute.

The tag and attributes below results in the printscreen below. How can I set the html-value by attribute?

```
<vaadin-rich-text-editor html-value="<p>Hello</p>"></vaadin-rich-text-editor>
```

In the element inspection I can see the value but the value which was set is just `<p><br></p>` instead of `<p>Hello</p>`. (see printscreens below)

[component view result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQhR6.png)
[google chrome developer tools element inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ2Wm.png)

Answer (score 5):

The `htmlValue` property in `<vaadin-rich-text-editor>`is read only, so it can't be used to set values. Setting HTML to a property in HTML opens up risks. You can set the value as HTML from JavaScript, with the `dangerouslySetHtmlValue(htmlValue)` function.

But as the name indicates, and the documentation says:

```
Sets content represented by HTML snippet into the editor.
The snippet is interpreted by [Quill's Clipboard matchers](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#matchers),
which may not produce the exactly input HTML.

**NOTE:** Improper handling of HTML can lead to cross site scripting (XSS) and failure to sanitize
properly is both notoriously error-prone and a leading cause of web vulnerabilities.
This method is aptly named to ensure the developer has taken the necessary precautions.
@param {string} htmlValue
```

I tested this code and it works:

```js
this.richTextEditor.dangerouslySetHtmlValue('<p>hello <b>world</b></p>');
```

[image: Picture of Rich Text Editor with set HTML]

You can see more in the [component documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/rich-text-editor/#value-format).

Comment: This is only possible in Vaadin 21. We use Vaadin 14, so is there in Vaadin 14 a way to set the html content of the text editor directly in the html/js with for example with some properties in the javascript (vaadin designer created) file? I currently link it by @Id(..) and set the value in Java. But I don't want to have an text editor instance in Java, it's memory consuming. (I want to use it in a "card" grid like the Vaadin start apps with a template renderer. But for now it's mandatory to set the value in Java, so I can't fully create a template renderer.